# Different ways to use react inside node and their pros/cons

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm working on a project and using `nodejs` as backend. I want to use `react` for the frontend. And currently, the way I know to use react is by creating a client folder inside it and using `create-react-app` and then running both the server separately and using the proxy to connect with the node backend. The other way I came to know is via  [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019) which basically involves installing react, reactdom, webpack etc, and using it directly inside the node app without having a separate server for react as in the case of `create-react-app`. So which way is better and what are their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to run both react and node in separate servers.

1. Create the react app using npx-create-react-app
2. Create the node app using npm init
   If both the folders are in the same directory you can use a npm package called concurrently and run both the servers with a single command. Also don't forget to install the npm package cors in your node app. If you don't , you'll get CORS errors from your API calls.

Imo using create react app is better than manually trying to configure webpack. Saves a lot of time and it's more easy to deploy.